# Android icons for applications

Tags: java, android, eclipse, icons

Can some one tell me some good web sites where i can download icons and images to use in my aplications??

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Icons.

Check here , 
http://www.androidicons.com/

and here ,

http://www.iconspedia.com/search/android/

and download android_ g1_icon.rar

http://www.allshadow.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=4058

and you may have look here , Though its for customizing the icons , if you search little you will get interesting icons that you may use in your apps.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=824656

Answer (score 3):

820+ Free Android Icons http://icons8.com/android-icons/. PNG format in all sizes from 24x24 to 512x512.

Comment: Let me re-phrase it: Icons8.com is a collection of 6000 icons to use in applications written for iOS 8, Android L, and Windows 8. It also has the tools to get an icon in the required format, size, and color, in 20 seconds.

Disclosure: I'm part of the team.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently found a set of free icon on http://glyphish.com/
There is a 200 item in free one. Hope it'll be helpful for you.

Comment: Although the website says they are "perfect for Android", they are really iOS style.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.iconfinder.com/ is nice

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Not sure I get what you mean Craigy, the question is about links to websites so the link is the essential part of the answer "is nice" is actually just a private opinion.

Comment: That's just an auto comment from review. It is not ideal to post only a link, you should summarize the content of the linked page and include the link for reference. However, this question is not a constructive one so this is a moot point when it becomes closed.

Answer (score -1):

Visit http://glyphish.com/download/glyphish-icons.zip  also...:)